# Call to a member function all() on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I had relationship made that is User and UserDetail.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table ='users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
    }
}
```

UserDetail.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table ='user_details';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'address', 'gender'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

but when I call it in the controller

```
  public function showUserInformation($id){
    $details= $this->user->detail;
    dd($details);
  }
```

> it returns null when I dd it. why was it happening?  Kindly help me
>   please

Comment: because `$this->user` donot have `detail` property.

Comment: Yeah i  corrected it because I just copied-pasted the two classes in this post that's why i forgot to change the relationship names but I already made the relationship inverse right before this

Comment: Can you please share dd($this->user); result?

Comment: make sure `$this` is the instance of Detail class.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal what do you mean sir? do i have to call on the model that has the belongsTo relatinship?

Comment: If you'll share dd($this->user); result or the class of your controller, where the public function showUserInformation($id){
    $details= $this->user->detail;
    dd($details);
  } lives, everything will be clear

Comment: @AvikAghajanyan 

`public function showDosageInformation($id){
    $photos = $this->dosage;
    dd($this->dosage);
  }`

its from  dosage and photo table. still has one to one rleationsihp

Comment: I need to see the whole class to understand who is your $this variable

Comment: @AvikAghajanyan                                                                                                        `
class MedicineController extends Controller {

  public function __construct(MedicineRepository $MedicineRepository,Dosage $dosage,Photo $photo, Medicine $medicine){
    $this->MedicineRepository = $MedicineRepository;
    $this->dosage = $dosage;
    $this->photo = $photo;
   
  }



  public function showDosageInformation(Dosage $id){
    $photos = $id->dosage->file_name;
    dd($this->dosage);
  }

}
`.

Comment: Thanks, so can you please try like this? public function showDosageInformation(Dosage $dosage) {
  $photos = $dosage->file_name;
  dd($photos);
 }

Comment: I think it's in the passing of the id. Maybe i have to clean up my code. You're all great thank you for helping me thru this

Answer (score 0):

Try (in your User.php)

```
public function detail(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
    }
```

change `user()` to `detail()`

Comment: I just copied the two classes that's why i forgot to change the relationship names but I already made the relationship inverse right.

Comment: try a dd($this->user->id) and check if this user has details in database

Comment: It doesn't return a thing sir

Comment: `public function showUserDetail($id){
    dd($this->user->id);
  }`

Comment: is it something like that sir?

Comment: dd($this->id) my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the id is a User model.
Change you function to this:

```
     public function showUserInformation(User $id){
         $details= $id->user->gender;  
         dd($details);
  }
```

Comment: Ok i'll take notice

Comment: try this   `$details= $id->user;`

Comment: if you still get the same error it means that your id does not exist or your relationships are not correct

Comment: Thanks to your help, But let me focus on the essential part o f the project and that's the dosage and the photo table

Comment: This is my model sir.

Comment: if not import this in your controller `use App\User;` @A.Sand

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'photos';
 protected $fillable = ['dosage_id','file_name','file_size','file_mime','file_path','created_by'];

 //get the dosage picture
 public function dosage(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Dosage');
 }
}
`

Comment: How to attach a formatted code. I'm sorry for my answers it's not formatted i'm a newb sorry

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dosage extends Model
{
 // protected $table ='dosages';

 protected $fillable = ['dosage_name', 'medicine_id', 'price'];
 
 public function medicine(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Medicine'); 
 }
 
 public function photo(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\Photo');
 }
}
`

Comment: My dosages and photos table contains like this

dosages
id|dosage_name|medicine_id|price|created_at|updated_at
1  1L                        3               200      timestamps

photos
id | dosage_id | file_name | file_size | file_mime | file_path | created_by
1         5                 58.jpg       31620 and so on

Comment: you should create another question if you want to ask another thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the '$this' keyword.

In your controller you have this piece of code:

```
  public function showUserInformation($id){
    $details= $this->user->detail;
    dd($details);
  }
```

in this code sample, $this points to the controller. So basically you're asking 'give me the user variable from this controller and get the details from it'. But does the controller has a user variable? (I'm guessing no since you're getting null errors).

You can just grab the model directly like so:

```
  public function showUserInformation($id){
    $details= UserDetail::whereUserId($id)->first();
    dd($details);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i managed to get the data but not through eloquent. I did traditional query. Thanks to all your help